# Optimize MySQL query with joining tables and ordering by columns from each table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table organizations with columns that contains nearly 900k rows.

id | name | rank

Also, I have a table favorites where storing organization's ids that were added to Favorite by users.

id | user_id | organization_id

The task is to fetch first 10 organizations sorted by organization's rank DESC, but in any case on top we need to show user's favorite organizations.
I am trying to do this with this query, but it takes 10 seconds:

```
SELECT o.*, f.id from organizations o 
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON o.id = f.organization_id AND f.user_id = 1
ORDER BY f.id DESC, o.rank
LIMIT 10
```

How to optimize this MySQL query?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see more than just the column names.

Comment: You want 20 rows?  Those ranked 1..10, plus the user's favorites?  Or you want the user's favorites ordered by ranking?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is subqueries:

```
SELECT o.*, f.id
FROM ((SELECT o.*, NULL as id
       FROM organizations o 
       ORDER BY o.rank DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) 
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT o.*, f.id
       FROM organizations o JOIN
            favorites f
            ON o.id = f.organization_id AND f.user_id = 1
      )
     ) fo
ORDER BY f.id DESC, o.rank
LIMIT 10;
```

For this, you want the following indexes `organizations(rank)`, `f(organization_id, user_id)`.

Comment: Error - Unknown column 'f.id' in 'field list'

Comment: There is no `f.id` in the first subquery. It should be `NULL as id`. Index on `f` should be `(user_id, organization_id)`. Second subquery should have `ORDER BY o.rank DESC LIMIT 10`. And there is no need for the outer SELECT - `(SELECT ... LIMIT 10) UNION ALL (SELECT ... LIMIT 10) ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10` also works.

Comment: @user1712438 . . . That should be `NULL` as id.